# Why is response time important in CPU scheduling?

Tags: operating-system, scheduling

I'm looking for an example of a job for which response time is important.

[One definition of response time is](https://www.cs.uic.edu/~jbell/CourseNotes/OperatingSystems/6_CPU_Scheduling.html):

> The time taken in an interactive program from the issuance of a command to the **commence** of a response to that command.

I've read that response time is important for interactivity, but I can't understand why. If the job isn't fully completed, what output could be produced that would be of interest to a user?

Wouldn't the user only care about how soon a job *finishes*, as that's the first time any output is produced?

For example, consider these two possible schedulings of two jobs:

```
Case 1: |---B---|---A---|
Case 2: |-A-|---B---|-A-|
```

Suppose that job A and B are issued at the same time, A being a command typed in by the user and B being some background process.

The response time for job A as I understand it would be shorter in case 2. As job A finishes (and produces output) at the same time in the two cases, I don't understand how the user benefits (or even notices) the better response time in case 2.

Comment: "I have no interest in the processor starting the job quickly" and "I just want the output as soon as possible" seem a bit fundamentally incompatible... In order to get output as soon as possible you need to have the job started quickly (and not interrupted, and ...)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have an answer to my own question. The problem was, I was just thinking about simple processes like `ls` that once issued runs for some amount of time and *then*, when they're finished, deliver their first and only output.

However, suppose job A in the example from the question is a program with multiple print statements. Output will in that case be produced *before the process is complete* (and some of the printouts may well occur during the first scheduled burst). It would thus make sense for interactivity to want to begin running such a process as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

When writing an operating system, one has to take into consideration what will the intended audience be. In some cases it matters most to finish jobs as quickly as possible (supercomputer systems), in some cases it matters most to be as responsive as possible (regular desktop systems), and in some cases it matters most to be as predictable as possible (real-time systems).

For **finishing jobs as fast as possible**, tasks should be interrupted the rarest possible (so big intervals between task switches are the best option). Here response time doesn't really matter much. It should be noted that task switches usually take some time (thousands of CPU cycles usually) due to having to save the state (including registers and paging structures) of the old task to memory and restore the state (including registers and paging structures) of the new task from memory. This also causes cache and TLB misses, since the cached information doesn't usually belong to the current process.

For **being the most responsive possible**, tasks should be interrupted as often as possible so the user doesn't experience the so-called lag. This is where response time is important. Note however that on interrupt-driven architectures (like x86) an interrupt from the keyboard or the mouse would automatically pause execution of the current task and call the interrupt handler, which processes the input and sends it to the appropriate program.

For **being the most predictable possible**, input should be processed neither too fast, neither too slow. This means that response time is constrained from both ways, thus being much more important than in "most responsive possible" designs. A misprediction can even be a fatal failure in mission-critical systems.

In a nutshell, importance of response time varies from design to design and can range from nearly unimportant to critical.